# Unable to load resource (.resx) file because it is not trusted

Tags: c#, windows

I am facing an issue while building windows source in Visual studio 2017. Showing the error message mentioned in the title.

Anyone have any idea about this error message?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally I could have resolved the issue as below:

> 1. Open the file explorer. Navigate to project/solution directory
> 2. Search for *.resx. --> You will get list of resx files
> 3. Right click the resx file, open the properties and check the option 'Unblock'
> 4. Repeat #3 for each resx file.
> 5. Reload the project.

Comment: More succinctly, open the file in windows explorer, right click - choose properties and check unblock.

Comment: Very quick and nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: There is no option in file properties to unblock

Comment: It's rather annoying having to do this in a project with 50+ .resx files... there has got to be an easier way to handle this?

Comment: Using Windows 11, there's no 'Unblock' button/option/checkbox anywhere on the File|Properties|General tab (only a field with the filename, the 'Change' button for setting the default application, and three 'Attributes' checkboxes). Could someone add some clarification here for to where this 'unblock' option is that all of these responses seem to keep referring to?